# How can I get gvim to use the system (GNOME) theme?

Tags: gnome, gvim

I use the dark theme on GNOME (Gnome Tweak Tool -> Appearance -> Global Dark Theme -> On), which looks great with Terminal, Files, and almost everything else. But Gvim still has a white window border, and it looks really out of place. How can I get Gvim to use my system theme?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of material within vim to manage color presentation.  Here is the part I think would be most helpful to you:

```
17. Color xterms                                xterm-color color-xterm

Most color xterms have only eight colors.  If you don't get colors with the
default setup, it should work with these lines in your .vimrc:
   :if &term =~ "xterm"
   :  if has("terminfo")
   :    set t_Co=8
   :    set t_Sf=<Esc>[3%p1%dm
   :    set t_Sb=<Esc>[4%p1%dm
   :  else
   :    set t_Co=8
   :    set t_Sf=<Esc>[3%dm
   :    set t_Sb=<Esc>[4%dm
   :  endif
   :endif
        [<Esc> is a real escape, type CTRL-V <Esc>]
You might want to change the first "if" to match the name of your terminal,
e.g. "dtterm" instead of "xterm".

Note: Do these settings BEFORE doing ":syntax on".  Otherwise the colors may
be wrong.
                                                        xiterm rxvt
The above settings have been mentioned to work for xiterm and rxvt too.
But for using 16 colors in an rxvt these should work with terminfo:
        :set t_AB=<Esc>[%?%p1%{8}%<%t25;%p1%{40}%+%e5;%p1%{32}%+%;%dm
        :set t_AF=<Esc>[%?%p1%{8}%<%t22;%p1%{30}%+%e1;%p1%{22}%+%;%dm

                                                        colortest.vim
To test your color setup, a file has been included in the Vim distribution.
To use it, execute this command:
   :runtime syntax/colortest.vim

Some versions of xterm (and other terminals, like the Linux console) can
output lighter foreground colors, even though the number of colors is defined
at 8.  Therefore Vim sets the "cterm=bold" attribute for light foreground
colors, when 't_Co' is 8.

                                                        xfree-xterm
To get 16 colors or more, get the newest xterm version (which should be
included with XFree86 3.3 and later).  You can also find the latest version
at:
        http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html
Here is a good way to configure it.  This uses 88 colors and enables the
termcap-query feature, which allows Vim to ask the xterm how many colors it
supports.
        ./configure --disable-bold-color --enable-88-color --enable-tcap-query
If you only get 8 colors, check the xterm compilation settings.
(Also see UTF8-xterm for using this xterm with UTF-8 character encoding).

This xterm should work with these lines in your .vimrc (for 16 colors):
   :if has("terminfo")
   :  set t_Co=16
   :  set t_AB=<Esc>[%?%p1%{8}%<%t%p1%{40}%+%e%p1%{92}%+%;%dm
   :  set t_AF=<Esc>[%?%p1%{8}%<%t%p1%{30}%+%e%p1%{82}%+%;%dm
   :else
   :  set t_Co=16
   :  set t_Sf=<Esc>[3%dm
   :  set t_Sb=<Esc>[4%dm
   :endif
        [<Esc> is a real escape, type CTRL-V <Esc>]

Without +terminfo, Vim will recognize these settings, and automatically
translate cterm colors of 8 and above to "<Esc>[9%dm" and "<Esc>[10%dm".
Colors above 16 are also translated automatically.

For 256 colors this has been reported to work:

   :set t_AB=<Esc>[48;5;%dm
   :set t_AF=<Esc>[38;5;%dm

Or just set the TERM environment variable to "xterm-color" or "xterm-16color"
and try if that works.

You probably want to use these X resources (in your ~/.Xdefaults file):
        XTerm*color0:                   #000000
        XTerm*color1:                   #c00000
        XTerm*color2:                   #008000
        XTerm*color3:                   #808000
        XTerm*color4:                   #0000c0
        XTerm*color5:                   #c000c0
        XTerm*color6:                   #008080
        XTerm*color7:                   #c0c0c0
        XTerm*color8:                   #808080
        XTerm*color9:                   #ff6060
        XTerm*color10:                  #00ff00
        XTerm*color11:                  #ffff00
        XTerm*color12:                  #8080ff
        XTerm*color13:                  #ff40ff
        XTerm*color14:                  #00ffff
        XTerm*color15:                  #ffffff
        Xterm*cursorColor:              Black

[Note: The cursorColor is required to work around a bug, which changes the
cursor color to the color of the last drawn text.  This has been fixed by a
newer version of xterm, but not everybody is using it yet.]

To get these right away, reload the .Xdefaults file to the X Option database
Manager (you only need to do this when you just changed the .Xdefaults file):
  xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults
```